When trying to simulate a transaction with Gnosis Safe it gives a GS013 error
When I tried a transaction that I used before, Gnosos Safe gave an error today. I could not understand why.
I have enough BNB in the safe and the token I want to send, but it still gives an error about the gas fee.
Can you help with why this is happening?
Tanderly link: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/327d5efb-60ee-4e25-ba7c-534b610cae41

This error occurs when the internal transaction fails (not necessarily when there is a problem in estimating gas). Could you make sure all your transaction parameters are correct, and/or provide more details on what you are trying to achieve? Since the contract you are trying to interact with (0x0a0bcb1cec38c2b57bb6db7dfd4186653a89fa91) is not public, it is difficult to understand what fails in this transaction. Thank you in advance  Best, Louis

I don't know the exact parameters of the transaction, but I was able to do the transaction before by entering only ABI, contract address and quantity. I don't understand why I can't do the same transaction now. Is it possible that something has changed in the way gnosis works since the last time I did the transaction?

Chances are you don't have enough tokens and/or ETH to perform the transaction. Without knowing the value that tries to be transferred, it will be difficult to be sure, though. Is there any way for you to get the parameters of the transaction? Best, Louis
